# Renew refresh tokens using Go oauth2 package?

Tags: go, oauth, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

It seems as if the expiry of refresh tokens is ignored in the oauth2 package for Go, as pointed to by this issue on its repository: https://github.com/golang/oauth2/issues/397. I am trying to achieve a sliding duration of refresh tokens, as defined in https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/refresh_tokens.html. However, using the refresh token to refresh access tokens stops working after a time equal to the lifespan of refresh tokens defined for the client has passed. In other words, I cannot seem to renew the lifespan of refresh tokens by using them.

Comment: That's an issue with the server then, isn't it? Either it doesn't prolong the lifetime of the refresh token, or it doesn't send a new refresh token together with the new access token, or the new refresh token has an incorrect lifespan. Seems like you have access to the server. Have you checked what it does, exactly?

Comment: @Peter The server implements the IdentityServer4 framework, and it handles sliding refresh tokens just fine with other clients not written in Go. Therefore I suspect that the issue lies in the oauth2 package, or my usage of it.

Comment: "The server works fine with other clients" isn't helpful if you're looking for a solution in Go, though. You'll have to figure out what the server does. I'd start by inspecting the response from the refresh request. To do so, you can wrap the client's Transport as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53007606/603316) (use DumpResponse instead of DumpRequestOut).